# jquery-html5-upload issue (Upload file on button click)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, file-upload, fileapi

I can't get the proper way to upload a file on button click using this plugin.

https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload

In documentation it says:

> ## Options
>
> #### Events
>
> All events except "change" used by plugin have prefix "html5_upload.".
>
> #### Events used by plugin
>
> It is not recommended to set handlers for this events manual.
>
> **start** Start upload selected files
>
> **cancelOne** Cancel upload of currently uploading file
>
> **cancelAll** Cancel current uploading
>
> **destroy** Removes traces of plugin work
>
> https://github.com/mihaild/jquery-html5-upload#options

I want to be able to do something like that.

```
$("#submit-button-1").click(function(){
$("#upload-src").html5_upload(start) //or something like that for each uploader
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer for your specific situation:

```
jQuery('#submit-button-1').on('click',function(){
  jQuery('#upload-src').triggerHandler('html5_upload.start');
})
```